# How to append at the start of two numbers separated by hyphen using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string: **'100 - 250'**

I want to append the pound symbol to start of each number so it becomes:

**£100 - £250**

What's the best way to do this using Javascript?

I tried using regex `/[0-9]/` to identify the numbers, I would have then just appended the pound symbol and recreated my string. But this regex identifies the individual numbers so when executing this regex on `'100 - 250'`, I am getting back `[1, 0...]`.

Comment: What did you try? What doesn't work?

Comment: I tried using regex /[0-9]/ to identify the numbers, I would have then just appended the pound symbol and recreated my string. But this regex identifies the individual numbers so when executing this regex on '100 - 250', I am getting back [1, 0...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```js
var str = "100 - 250";
str = str.replace(/(?=\b\d+\b)/g, '£');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\b\d+\b/g, '£$&');` seems more efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: May be,  haven't done any benchmarks. But for a single replacement, I don't think it is significant.

Comment: @Toto, you use `/g`, it is not single replacement. A lookahead will check all the positions in the input string. I'd avoid zero-length matches whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var regex = /(\d+)(\s*\-\s*)(\d+)/,
    myString = '100 - 250';

myString.replace(regex, "£$1$2£$3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice one-liner

```
str.match(/\d+/g).map(function(num) { return "£"+num; }).join(" - ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "100 - 250";
var arr = str.match(/\d+/g);
arr.forEach(function(item, index, ar){ar[index] = "$"+item;});
console.log("output - "+arr.join(" - "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution almost complete in case you need to only deal with integer values.

In order to add a pound sign in front of each digit at the number start use

```
str = str.replace(/\b[0-9]/g, '£$&');
                   ^^           ^^
```

That is, you needed a **word boundary** (`\b`) and a backreference to the whole match (`$&`) in your replacement pattern.

Note that `/g` modifier will make *multiple replacements* if there is more than  1 match in the string.

```js
var str = "100 - 200";
str = str.replace(/\b[0-9]/g, '£$&');
console.log(str);
```

A bonus solution for integers *and floats*:

```js
var str = "100 - 200 - 550.55";
str = str.replace(/(^|[^.])\b([0-9])/g, '$1£$2');
// or
// str = str.replace(/\d*\.?\d+/g, '£$&');
console.log(str);
```